# Integral of a vector difference

Tags: calculus

Not sure how to deal with this problem:

$$\dfrac {d\overrightarrow {h}}{dt}=\overrightarrow {r_1}\times \left( -\dfrac {m}{\left( \overrightarrow {r_2}-\overrightarrow {r_1}\right) ^{2}}\right)$$

where $r_2$ and $r_1$ are vectors. The parameter $t$ represents time. $h$ is the specific angular momentum. The vector direction of the right side term, I suppose, would be $(r_2-r_1)$.

This is as far as I get. But I’m not sure if I’m headed in the right direction:

$$\dfrac {d\overrightarrow {h}}{dt}=\overrightarrow {r_1}\times \left( -\dfrac {m}{\left( \overrightarrow {r_2}-\overrightarrow {r_1}\right) ^{3}}\left( \overrightarrow {r_2}-\overrightarrow {r_1}\right) \right)$$

$$\int \dfrac {d\overrightarrow {h}}{dt} dt=\int -\dfrac {m}{\left( \overrightarrow {r_2}-\overrightarrow {r_1}\right) ^{3}}r_2r_1\sin \theta\ dt$$

$$h=\int \dfrac {mr_2r_1\sin \theta }{\left( \left( r_{2}\cos \theta _{2}-r_{1}\cos \theta _{1}\right) +\left( r_{2}\sin \theta _{2}-r_{1}\sin \theta _{1}\right) \right) ^{\frac {3}{2}}}\ dt$$

$$h=\dfrac {mr_{2}r_{1}\sin \theta }{\left( \overrightarrow {r}_{2}-\overrightarrow {r}_{1}\right) ^{3}}t+C$$